# How to run and implement 24/7 notification listener in Background Service of Android app from api level 16 till api level 28

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I am trying to implement a long running android service which keeps running irrespective of app is running or not. Bu this service is getting killed when i close the app in Android pie verson

Below is my code for service:

```
 public class LocationNotificator extends Service {
        private static int FOREGROUND_ID = 1338;

        public LocationNotificator() {
        }

        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Log.d("Location checker", "Service running");
    //My code is here
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                startMyOwnForeground();
            else
                startForeground(FOREGROUND_ID,
                        buildForegroundNotification("abc"));
            stopForeground(true);
            return START_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        }

        private Notification buildForegroundNotification(String filename) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

            b.setOngoing(true);

            b.setContentTitle("Some Title")
                    .setContentText("some File name")
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
                    .setTicker("downloading");

            return (b.build());
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        private void startMyOwnForeground() {
            String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.simpleapp";
            String channelName = "My Background Service";
            NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
            chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            assert manager != null;
            manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.talentify_logo_red)
                    .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
                    .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                    .build();
            startForeground(2, notification);
        }
    }
```

I want this service to be long running how should i make this service long running

Comment: You need to use a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services). Use [`startForeground()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)), available since API level 5. It'll work for everything after that.

Comment: Can give a sample code for this please

Comment: Does foreground run with notification? I don't want to show notification

Comment: A foreground service does require a notification bar item. If what you want is literally a `Service` that "keeps running irrespective of app is running" (a service that never gets killed), then this is your only practical option. If you just need it to run for a brief time, after a broadcast intent comes in, then you should be able to use the code you have (if this is the case, please be more specific about the problem you are having). By the way, the "RESTART_SERVICE" trick is a hack and to my knowledge it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah my requirements is exactly keep running the service irrespective of app is running or not. It should get started when Android device reboot/boot.

Comment: I m so confused should i go with intent service or normal service. How can i achieve it to be continous running service

Comment: Please refer to my previous comment. The choice is no more complicated than what I've explained.

Comment: Updated the code. Please check and suggest what should i do. I did try that thing but it seem not working. Its getting killed as soon as i close the app. I dont get a straight way to resolving it. I need a service which keeps running on all the version.

Comment: You're saying the notification bar item is being removed when you close the app? And there's no stack trace?

Comment: the service is running as long as app is running. When i remove the app from background and service also getting stopped.

Comment: do u have the sample service code which keep running in background forever?

Comment: I do not but googling for startForeground() should get you plenty of examples. I did not see any mistakes in your code at first glance but I must ask you to precisely describe the notification icon behavior.

Comment: i m avoiding notification to be displayed. I want service which keep running and connected to websocket as soon as server send the message it would display a notification to user

Comment: I just need a service which keep running always and when phone get reboot it get started keep running on irrespective of the app. There are ton of problem right now if i register a broadcast reciever i have to unregister it in ondestroy. If i unregister if how can i listen to app state. From oreo onward BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast is not working. How can i keep running the service for all devices its quite a mess now/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183120/discussion-between-feroz-siddiqui-and-greeble31).